# Java While Loop Code not Working

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm working on a part of a Gui program, but I'm stuck on this code. When the user clicks a button, it makes the button disabled (that works), but the loop isn't working at all. I used a while loop, and just made it do a simple math equation.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            Enable.setEnabled(false);   
            Date d = new Date();
            int hrs = d.getHours();
            int mins = d.getMinutes();

            while(1 +1) == 2) { 
                    if(hrs == 17 & mins == 30) {
                        Function function = new Function();
                    }
            }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What did you expect to happen? What is happening?

Comment: What are you trying to *do* in your while loop?

Comment: Did you typo `&&` for `&` only here or is it like that in your code?

Comment: Well I want a new instance of my 'Function' class.

Comment: Remember 5th grade you should have learned about the order of operations. The same applies to the mathematics performed in our code. See PEDMAS.

Comment: No typo, but I tried &&, and it still didn't work.

Comment: (1+1) == 2 and your gui gonna freeze and stackoverflow

Comment: I know my Gui will freeze, I don't really care about that right now.

Comment: `&` is a bitwise comparison, you'll want to use `&&` for logical comparisons.

Comment: Try putting something like `System.out.println("Testing")` instead of the function bit, it's possible the loop is working fine, it's just not doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
        while( (1 + 1) == 2) {
```

Comment: I just checked the operator precedence, + is higher than ==, so it's fine without the brackets. [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are never updating `hrs` or `mins`. Unless it happens to be 17:30 when you run first run this app, it will never work.

```
while (true) {
    Date d = new Date();
    int hrs = d.getHours();
    int mins = d.getMinutes();

    if(hrs == 17 && mins == 30) {
        Function f = new Function();
    }
}
```

Note: This is called [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). It is generally bad practice to use it.

Answer (score 1):

this will be an infinite loop and it will never  end because the loop condition is always true. therefore you can modify your while loop as follows `while(true)` . but keep it mind that having an infinite loop is a BAD Coding practice..

Answer (score 0):

This wont do anything unless it happend to be 5:30 when they click the button? Just loops forever?

If you want to ensure your entering your loop why not just use `while(true)`

Answer (score 0):

`while(true)` worked for me. try this.